# How to configure Protractor to use Cucumber

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

As of [0.20.1](http://ng-learn.org/2014/03/Protractor-0-20-1/) Cucumber is now fully supported in Protractor but I'm battling to find any documentation on how to configure it properly. Any idea how you would setup world.js?

I have found this example at https://github.com/whyvez/angular-cucumber-example/blob/master/features/support/world.coffee but I'm not sure if you would still need to specify all the require modules and configuration as the protractor config file (referenceConf.js) would have all this info already.

```
assert = require 'assert'
path = require 'path'

protractor = require 'protractor'
webdriver = require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = new webdriver.Builder().
  usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub').
  withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
  build()

driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(100000)

ptor = protractor.wrapDriver driver

class World
  constructor: (callback) ->
    @browser = ptor
    @By = protractor.By
    @assert = assert
    callback()

module.exports.World = World
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have created a sample project to show how to configure Protractor with Cucumber and make use of the World.

The World is a place to share commonalities between different scenarios so that you can keep you code organised.

Actually, all you need is to create your world.js file in a folder called /support under /features. You would place there your hooks as well. Every property or function there will be available in your step definitions.

world.js:

```
module.exports = function() {

  this.World = function World(callback) {
    this.prop = "Hello from the World!";

    this.greetings = function(name, callback) {
      console.log("\n----Hello " + name);
      callback();
    };

    callback();
}
```

And then in your steps:

```
var sampleSteps = function() {

    this.Given(/^this is the first sample$/, function (callback) {
      console.log("\n----" + this.prop);
      callback();
    });

    this.Given(/^this is the second sample$/, function (callback) {
      this.greetings("everybody", callback);
    });

};

module.exports = sampleSteps;
```

Your protractor.js configuration file would look something like this:

```
exports.config = {

  specs: [
    'e2e/features/*.feature'
  ],

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8081/',

  framework: 'cucumber',

};
```

This the GitHub repository.

https://github.com/plopcas/st-protractor-cucumber

Hope this helps.

Comment: Pedro, i have used your example to make my test work but when i use expect it fails. which library shall i use for expect in this case?

Comment: Difficult to tell without seeing the error, but I guess you are trying to use the "expect" which is a Jasmine global function. But given that you are using Cucumber here, you do not have that function. I like to use Chai.js. It is pretty good assertion library. All you need is var chai = require('chai'); var expect = chai.expect; and then use it in your steps. You might need to use "chai-as-promised" if you are using promises. Take into account that the syntax is different than the Jasmine-based expect function.

Comment: thanks Pedro, i got away from using expect and using if condition to meet the criteria and then callback(). e.g. if (data && data.indexOf("World") > 0)
                callback();
            else
                callback.fail(new Error("Expected to be on page with searchTerm " + searchTerm));

Comment: Hello All! I've been trying to run the tests, but I keep getting this: 
```
launcher] Error: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/frameworks/cucumber.js:132:36
at Function.promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:650:9)
```

Comment: For my previous comment, I'm trying to run with protractor path/to/config.js

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [protractor-cucumbe](https://github.com/AndrewKeig/protractor-cucumber) -- it comes with selenium-webdriver, supports Promises, and is well documented.

It seems to require minimal configuration, and what is required is clearly documented.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten good milage from this setup

```
  class ChtWorld
    chai = require('chai');
    chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

    constructor:  ->
      @browser = @protractor = require('protractor').getInstance()
      @By = @protractor.By
      chai.use(chaiAsPromised)
      @expect= chai.expect


  module.exports= ->
    this.World= (callback) ->
      w = new ChtWorld()
      callback(w)
```

Since protractor is already setup, just getting a reference to it is sufficient
(note that for Cucumber to correctly load up the new world, the modules.exports has to be just right).

As a side note, this is located in features/support/world.coffee, and not explicitly added to the 'requires' list (trying to do that got me into Gherkin Lexing error problems).

Answer (score 0):

Add it as a framework in the configuration file:

```
exports.config = {
  // set to "custom" instead of cucumber.
  framework: 'custom',

  // path relative to the current config file
  frameworkPath: 'protractor-cucumber-framework'

  // relevant cucumber command line options
  cucumberOpts: {
    format: "summary"
  }
};
```

More information here: [Protractor Frameworks](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/frameworks)